# CEF3 crashes on Windows XP

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

I hope that all is well.

I'm trying to develop an application on Visual C++ 2010 with [Chromium Embedded Framework 3](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/w/list). The application runs perfectly on Windows 7. However when ran on Windows XP, it crashes. The first solution that I did was to check if there are missing DLLs.

[image]

When I check the debug file, it returns these errors:

```
[0520/140334:ERROR:gpu_info_collector_win.cc(103)] Can't retrieve a valid WinSAT assessment.
[0520/140336:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
```

Comment: Maybe a little more information ? How do you build it (libcef_dll_wrapper ?), when does it crash ? Hang in there, the way to have a fully functional cef build is kind of long (at least it was for me).

Comment: I used the build from the Dev Trunk (cef_binary_3.1921.1661_windows32.zip), removed CEFclient and edited the cefsimple. The application made a long way without any issues on Windows 7. Unfortunately, it crashes on Windows XP.

It crashes a few seconds after the exe is clicked. Here are the images of the errors:

http://imgur.com/LC9kIwQ,Cq1lYqU,oto3MKl#0
http://imgur.com/LC9kIwQ,Cq1lYqU,oto3MKl#1
http://imgur.com/LC9kIwQ,Cq1lYqU,oto3MKl#2

Comment: don't you have at least a callstack when it crashes, can help us figure out what's going on? Can't help you more with that less information

Comment: This is the one that's causing the error:

`[0520/140334:ERROR:gpu_info_collector_win.cc(103)] Can't retrieve a valid WinSAT assessment.
> [0520/140336:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox`

@Kiroxas

Comment: Are you compiling libcef_wrapper_dll along with your application ? .cc extensions seems like libcef_wrapper issues

Comment: Yes. My project depends on libcef_wrapper_dll. What issues? 

PS: I apologize I'm not good in C++. @Kiroxas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54020/discussion-between-kiroxas-and-benj).

Answer (score 1):

Running the application in Visual Studio 2013 solved the issue. Perhaps the sandbox is built using this version.